# kmail folder disappeared

Tags: kmail

I'm running Kubuntu 14.10 with kmail 4.14.1.  After stopping and restarting kmail, a subfolder of one of my mail folders disappeared without a trace.  How can I find it, or at least find the messages that were in it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be an unfortunate interaction between kmail and Dropbox relating to case sensitivity.  I finally figured out a string that appeared only in one of the missing messages, and then did a search for it.  That led me to a Dropbox "Case Conflict" folder, and all the missing messages were in that folder.